# How to get a cell range to select and copy based off of cell value

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I want to select and copy a cell range.  I have the user choosing what data they want from a combo box.  Once the data is chosen, they hit a button that runs the code below:

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click()
'''''WHAT HAPPENS WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED'''''

'TARGET CELL REFERENCE
Dim TargetRow As Integer
TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1, Sheets("Inprocess").Range("Sku_Range1"), 0)
Sheets("Data").Range("G3").Value = TargetRow

'COPY & SELECT CELL RANGE FROM TARGET CELL
Dim FndStr As String
FndStr = TargetRow
Dim FndVal As Range
Set FndVal = Columns("J:J").Find(What:=FndStr, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If FndVal Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "LP not found!!"
    Else
        FndVal.Select
        Range(Selection.Offset(0, -1), Selection.Offset(0, 2)).Copy
    End If


End Sub
```

My issue is that FndVal is returning nothing and I cant seem to figure out why.  Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is in a `UserForm` try specifing the `Sheet` you are refering to.

Example:

```
Set FndVal = Sheets("Data").Columns("J:J").Find(What:=FndStr, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

Comment: FndVal Still returned a value of nothing.

Comment: can you give at least sample data to recreate the issue? because this code is working for me, it returns nothing only when the value is not found

Comment: It worked!  I spelled the sheet name wrong.  Thanks for the help